# variable substitution not happening correctly

Tags: automount

I've been using the script from [centos wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WindowsShares) (method 5) for months now. A few weeks ago it stopped working, looking at the logs it seems that the variable substitution is not taking place.

Here's a what the script tells you to do:

```
[/etc/auto.master] -- append  
/mnt/smb /etc/auto.smb.top --timeout=600 --ghost

[/etc/auto.smb.top] -- new file  
* -fstype=autofs,-Dhost=& file:/etc/auto.smb.sub

[/etc/auto.smb.sub] -- new file  
* -fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/root/mycreds.txt,uid=500,gid=100 ://${host}/&

[/root/mycreds.txt] -- new file  
usenrame=username
password=<secret password>
```

Then when ls'ing somewhere that should automount, this is what the output is in journalctl:

```
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: handle_packet: type = 3  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: handle_packet_missing_indirect: token 436, name 172.16.1.105, request pid 31794  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: lookup_mount: lookup(file): looking up 172.16.1.105  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: lookup_mount: lookup(file): 172.16.1.105 -> -fstype=autofs,-Dhost=& file:/etc/auto.smb.sub  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: parse_mount: parse(sun): expanded entry: -fstype=autofs,-Dhost=172.16.1.105 file:/etc/auto.smb.sub  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: parse_mount: parse(sun): gathered options: fstype=autofs,-Dhost=172.16.1.105  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: parse_mount: parse(sun): dequote("file:/etc/auto.smb.sub") -> file:/etc/auto.smb.sub  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: parse_mount: parse(sun): core of entry: options=fstype=autofs,-Dhost=172.16.1.105, loc=file:/etc/auto.smb.sub  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: sun_mount: parse(sun): mounting root /mnt/smb, mountpoint 172.16.1.105, what file:/etc/auto.smb.sub, fstype autofs, options -Dhost=172.16.1.105  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: do_mount: file:/etc/auto.smb.sub /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105 type autofs options -Dhost=172.16.1.105 using module autofs  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: mount_mount: mount(autofs): mountpoint=/mnt/smb/172.16.1.105 what=file:/etc/auto.smb.sub options=-Dhost=172.16.1.105  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: automount_path_to_fifo: fifo name /run/autofs.fifo-mnt-smb-172.16.1.105  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: lookup_nss_read_map: reading map file /etc/auto.smb.sub  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: do_init: parse(sun): init gathered global options: (null)  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: mounted indirect on /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105 with timeout 600, freq 150 seconds  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: st_ready: st_ready(): state = 0 path /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: ghosting enabled  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: dev_ioctl_send_ready: token = 436  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: mounted /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: handle_packet: type = 3  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: handle_packet_missing_indirect: token 437, name Super Secret Dir, request pid 31794  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105/Super Secret Dir  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: lookup_mount: lookup(file): looking up Super Secret Dir  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: lookup_mount: lookup(file): Super Secret Dir -> -fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/root/mycreds.txt,uid=500,gid=100 ://${host}/&  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: parse_mount: parse(sun): expanded entry: -fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/root/mycreds.txt,uid=500,gid=100 ://test/Quickbooks\ Company\ Files  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: parse_mount: parse(sun): gathered options: fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/root/mycreds.txt,uid=500,gid=100  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: parse_mount: parse(sun): dequote("://test/Quickbooks\ Company\ Files") -> ://test/Super Secret Dir  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: parse_mount: parse(sun): core of entry: options=fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/root/mycreds.txt,uid=500,gid=100, loc=://test/Super Secret Dir  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: sun_mount: parse(sun): mounting root /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105, mountpoint Super Secret Dir, what //test/Super Secret Dir, fstype cifs, options rw,credentials=/root/mycreds.txt,uid=500,gid=100  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: do_mount: //test/Super Secret Dir /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105/Super Secret Dir type cifs options rw,credentials=/root/mycreds.txt,uid=500,gid=100 using module generic  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: mount_mount: mount(generic): calling mkdir_path /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105/Super Secret Dir  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: mount_mount: mount(generic): calling mount -t cifs -s -o rw,credentials=/root/mycreds.txt,uid=500,gid=100 //test/Super Secret Dir /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105/Super Secret Dir  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: spawn_mount: mtab link detected, passing -n to mount  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: >> Unable to find suitable address.  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: mount(generic): failed to mount //test/Super Secret Dir (type cifs) on /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105/Super Secret Dir  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: dev_ioctl_send_fail: token = 437  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: failed to mount /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105/Super Secret Dir  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: handle_packet: type = 3  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: handle_packet_missing_indirect: token 438, name Super Secret Dir, request pid 31794  
Oct 16 10:47:47 test.example.com automount[31764]: dev_ioctl_send_fail: token = 438
```

log from /var/log/message:

```
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: handle_packet: type = 3  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: handle_packet_missing_indirect: token 446, name Quickbooks Company Files, request pid 2035  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105/Quickbooks Company Files  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: lookup_mount: lookup(file): looking up Quickbooks Company Files  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: lookup_mount: lookup(file): Quickbooks Company Files -> -fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/root/mycreds.txt,uid=500,gid=100 ://${host}/&  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: parse_mount: parse(sun): expanded entry: -fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/root/mycreds.txt,uid=500,gid=100 ://test/Quickbooks\ Company\ Files  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: parse_mount: parse(sun): gathered options: fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/root/mycreds.txt,uid=500,gid=100  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: parse_mount: parse(sun): dequote("://test/Quickbooks\ Company\ Files") -> ://test/Quickbooks Company Files  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: parse_mount: parse(sun): core of entry: options=fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/root/mycreds.txt,uid=500,gid=100, loc=://test/Quickbooks Company Files  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: sun_mount: parse(sun): mounting root /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105, mountpoint Quickbooks Company Files, what //test/Quickbooks Company Files, fstype cifs, options rw,credentials=/root/mycreds.txt,uid=500,gid=100  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: do_mount: //test/Quickbooks Company Files /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105/Quickbooks Company Files type cifs options   rw,credentials=/root/mycreds.txt,uid=500,gid=100 using module generic  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: mount_mount: mount(generic): calling mkdir_path /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105/Quickbooks Company Files  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: mount_mount: mount(generic): calling mount -t cifs -s -o rw,credentials=/root/mycreds.txt,uid=500,gid=100 //test/Quickbooks Company Files /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105/Quickbooks Company Files  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: spawn_mount: mtab link detected, passing -n to mount  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: >> Unable to find suitable address.  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: mount(generic): failed to mount //test/Quickbooks Company Files (type cifs) on /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105/Quickbooks Company Files  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: dev_ioctl_send_fail: token = 446  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: failed to mount /mnt/smb/172.16.1.105/Quickbooks Company Files  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: handle_packet: type = 3  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: handle_packet_missing_indirect: token 447, name Quickbooks Company Files, request pid 2035  
Oct 16 11:02:18 test automount[31764]: dev_ioctl_send_fail: token = 447
```

The first thing that looks 'weird' is it's only using the sub domain of the host. But that's not really important in this situation.
So if I change the variable name to something like TARGET the substitution is blank giving :///Quickbooks\ Company\ Files

Comment: I just ran into this as well, did you ever find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Is that a typo on usenrame? Did you specify `vers=1.0` or perhaps `vers=3.0` to the mount command? I [posted a slightly different issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/881260/no-dialect-specified-on-mount-error-where-to-set-vers-1-0-with-autofs-fedora-26) but perhaps you may find your answer there.